# What program lock the file

Tags: delphi, file, locking, handle

I need a program to overwrite the file, but sometimes some process is lock it. How to check which process locks a file, and how to unlock it? What functions should I use?

I found on the Internet such a code, but it doesn't work me.

```
unit proc;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, Grids, ValEdit, MTSUtilsUnit, TLHelp32,
  Menus, PsAPI;

type
  TApp = class
    fPID: Integer;
    fPArentPID: Integer;
    fPIDName: string;
    fThread: Integer;
    fDLLName: TStringList;
    fDLLPath: TStringList;
    fDescription: string;
  end;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Panel3: TPanel;
    Panel4: TPanel;
    Splitter2: TSplitter;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    kill1: TMenuItem;
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    function GetApps(AppName: string): TStringList;
    function GetInfo(PID: Integer): string;
    function Kill(PID: Integer): Boolean;
    procedure kill1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure StringGrid1SelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
      var CanSelect: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;
  ApplicationList: TStringList;
  row: Integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TForm2.Kill(PID: Integer): Boolean;
var fHandle: THandle;
begin
  fHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, BOOL(0), PID);
  if TerminateProcess(fHandle, 0) then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False;

  CloseHandle(fHandle);
end;

procedure TForm2.kill1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
  fApp: TApp;
begin
  if Kill(StrToInt(StringGrid1.Cells[1, row])) then
  begin
    ApplicationList.Delete(row);
    StringGrid1.RowCount := ApplicationList.Count;
    for i := 1 to ApplicationList.Count - 1 do
    begin
      fApp := TApp(ApplicationList.Objects[i]);
      Form2.StringGrid1.Cells[0,i] := fApp.fPIDName;
      Form2.StringGrid1.Cells[1,i] := IntToStr(fApp.fPID);
    end;
    MessageBox(0, 'Terminate successfully', 'Kill', MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK);
  end
  else
    MessageBox(0, 'Could not terminate process', 'Kill', MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_OK);
end;

procedure TForm2.StringGrid1SelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  var CanSelect: Boolean);
var fApp: TApp;
begin
  row := ARow;
  RichEdit1.Lines.Clear();
  if ApplicationList.Count >= row then
  begin
    fApp := TApp(ApplicationList.Objects[row]);
    RichEdit1.Lines.Add(fApp.fDescription);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
  fApp: TApp;
  sItem: string;
  CanSelect: Boolean;
begin
  for i := 0 to ApplicationList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    fApp := TApp(ApplicationList.Objects[i]);
    FreeAndNil(fApp.fDLLName);
    FreeAndNil(fApp.fDLLPath);
    FreeAndNil(fApp);
  end;
  FreeAndNil(ApplicationList);

  ApplicationList := GetApps(Edit1.Text);
  StringGrid1.RowCount := ApplicationList.Count;
  for i := 0 to ApplicationList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    fApp := TApp(ApplicationList.Objects[i]);
    StringGrid1.Cells[0,i] := fApp.fPIDName;
    StringGrid1.Cells[1,i] := IntToStr(fApp.fPID);
  end;
  StringGrid1.OnSelectCell(Self, 0, 1, CanSelect);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringGrid1.Cells[0,0] := 'Name';
  StringGrid1.Cells[1,0] := 'PID';
end;

function TForm2.GetInfo(PID: Integer): string;
var fHandle: THandle;
  fModule: TModuleEntry32;
  sInfo: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  sInfo := 'DLL Name: %s'#13#10 +
           'DLL Path: %s'#13#10 +
           'ModuleId: %d'#13#10;

  fHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, PID);

  if fHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  if Module32First(fHandle, fModule) then
  repeat
    if SameText(ExtractFileExt(fModule.szModule), '.dll') then
    begin
      sInfo := Format(sInfo, [fModule.szModule, fModule.szExePath, fModule.th32ModuleID]);
      Result := Result + sInfo;
    end;
  until not Module32Next(fHandle, fModule);
end;

function TForm2.GetApps(AppName: string): TStringList;
var fHandle: THandle;
  fModHandle: THandle;
  fProcess: TProcessEntry32;
  fModule: TMODULEENTRY32;
  App: TApp;
  i: Integer;
  IsDLL: Boolean;
  IsProcess: Boolean;
  fDesc: string;
  sPath: string;
begin
  IsDLL := False;
  IsProcess := False;


  Result := TStringList.Create();
  Result.Clear();
  fDesc := 'DLL Name: %s'#13#10 +
           'DLL Path: %s'#13#10 +
           'ModuleId: %d'#13#10;

  fHandle := CreateToolHelp32SnapShot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  fProcess.dwSize := SizeOf(fProcess);

  IsProcess := Process32First(fHandle, fProcess);

  while IsProcess do
  begin
    App := TApp.Create();
    App.fDLLName := TStringList.Create();
    App.fDLLPath := TStringList.Create();
    fModHandle := CreateToolHelp32SnapShot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, fProcess.th32ProcessID);
    IsDLL := Module32First(fModHandle, fModule);
    while IsDLL do
    begin
      if Edit1.Text <> '' then
        sPath := fModule.szModule
      else
        sPath := ExtractFileExt(fModule.szModule);
      if SameText(sPath, Edit1.Text + '.dll') then
      begin
        App.fPID := fProcess.th32ProcessID;
        App.fPIDName := fProcess.szExeFile;
        App.fDLLName.Add(fModule.szModule);
        App.fDLLPath.Add(fModule.szExePath);
        App.fDescription := App.fDescription +
          Format(fDesc, [fModule.szModule, fModule.szExePath, fModule.th32ModuleID]);
      end;
      IsDLL := Module32Next(fModHandle, fModule)
    end;
    if App.fDLLName.Count > 0 then
      Result.AddObject(IntToStr(App.fPID), App);
    IsProcess := Process32Next(fHandle, fProcess);
  end;
  CloseHandle(fHandle);
  Result.Count;
end;

end.
```

Comment: this sounds like you want someone to do the job for you!! search for "check if file is in use" or similar terms on google, I'm sure you will find enough information...

Answer (score 2):

You should not unlock the file yourself this will lead to lost data! Leave it to the user and instead show an error and explaining which process holds open the file.

This solution here will help you to do so:
http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2011/01/03/cannot-access-files-but-need-the-origin

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).  It will show you which processes have which files opened, and will allow you to close individual files.